# python3//way to change string item in list not changing the item itself but changing part of the item?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way to change string item in the list not changing the item itself but changing just part of the item?

For example:

```
list1 = ["#ab","^cd"]
```

I want to change the first item, `"#ab"` into `" ab"` (a into blank) 
not using `list1[0]=" ab"` and module

Comment: What does `not using /list1[0]=" ab"/` mean exactly?

Comment: How *do* you want to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this since mutation of the string cannot be done in-place, any operations on it will result in a new string that needs to be assigned.

You can do this in whatever fashion you like, e.g:

```
list[0] = list[0].replace('#', ' ')
```

Skipping the assignment part (`list[0] =`) would result in a new string, `' ab'`, getting created and then simply dumped.